# phone gap Cordova build command is failed to causes Build Failure

Tags: android, cordova

The following error is appearing when cordova build command is entered.
Please help me out : The following are version i used to setup phone gap:
Cordova version: 4.2.0
    Phone Gap version :4.2.0-0.24.2
    jdk:1.8.0_25
    Android platform-19
    Tool: 21.1.2

Blockquote

```
Error as Follows:

D:\PhonegapWorkspace\hello>cordova build
Running command: D:\PhonegapWorkspace\hello\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat

Buildfile: D:\PhonegapWorkspace\hello\platforms\android\build.xml

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 24.0.2
 [checkenv] Installed at D:\AndroidSdk\sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: CordovaApp
  [gettype] Project Type: Application

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 21.1.2
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for CordovaApp...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4.2
[gettarget] API level:        19
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for CordovaApp...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency]
[dependency] ------------------
[dependency] Ordered libraries:
[dependency]
[dependency] ------------------
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...

nodeps:

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 24.0.2
 [checkenv] Installed at D:\AndroidSdk\sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: CordovaApp
  [gettype] Project Type: Android Library

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 21.1.2
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for CordovaApp...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4.2
[gettarget] API level:        19
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\PhonegapWorkspace\hello\platforms\android\CordovaLib
\ant-build\rsObj
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\PhonegapWorkspace\hello\platforms\android\CordovaLib
\ant-build\rsLibs
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for CordovaApp...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] No Libraries
[dependency]
[dependency] ------------------

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Found Deleted Target File
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Found new input file
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] Generating BuildConfig class.

-pre-compile:

-compile:

BUILD FAILED//Here it is failing to build
D:\AndroidSdk\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:601: The following error occurred while ex
ecuting this line:
D:\AndroidSdk\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:720: The following error occurred while ex
ecuting this line:
D:\AndroidSdk\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:734: Class not found: javac1.8

Total time: 2 seconds

D:\PhonegapWorkspace\hello\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,ant,debug,-f,D:\PhonegapWorkspace
\hello\platforms\android\build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-ge
n
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: D:\PhonegapWorkspace\hello\platforms
\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 1
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project

D:\PhonegapWorkspace\hello>
```

Comment: try this command ant -version and post the output

Comment: ok i think porper path is missing may be JAVA_HOME

Comment: Thank you for your reply,
I changed the java version jdk1.8.0_25 to jdk 1.7.0_75 Its build successfully..
Can you clarify is there any dependency on versions of jdk.
Thank you....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ant version 1.9.x the jdk 8 is compatible

For ant verison below 1.9.x you need jdk 7.

Hence check ant version via `ant -verion` and add jdk appropriately.